# Native CXF integration in grails

Tags: java, web-services, grails, cxf

Does somebody know how to integrate the cxf framework without using the cxf plugin? I have already published a simple service, but my problem is to inject existing grails service bean in the cxf jaxws bean.

In applicationContext.xml i'm using following definition

```
<jaxws:server id="jaxwsService" serviceClass="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorld" address="/hello">
    <jaxws:serviceBean>
        <bean class="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorldImpl">
            <property name="halloService"><ref bean="helloWorld"></ref></property>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:serviceBean>
  </jaxws:server>
```

The helloWorld bean is a normal grails serivce class. During startup i get following exception.

Cannot resolve reference to bean 'helloWorld' while setting bean
    property 'halloService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'helloWorld' is defined

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml"/>


    <bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
        <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="grailsResourceLoader" ref="grailsResourceLoader" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
        <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
        <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
        <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceLoader" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceLoaderFactoryBean">
        <property name="grailsResourceHolder" ref="grailsResourceHolder" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="grailsResourceHolder" scope="prototype" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsResourceHolder">
        <property name="resources">
              <value>classpath*:**/grails-app/**/*.groovy</value>
        </property>
    </bean>    

   <bean id="characterEncodingFilter"
      class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
        <property name="encoding">
          <value>utf-8</value>
        </property>
   </bean>

    <jaxws:server id="jaxwsService" serviceClass="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorld" address="/hello">
    <jaxws:serviceBean>
        <bean class="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorldImpl">
            <property name="halloService"><ref bean="halloService"></ref></property>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:serviceBean>
  </jaxws:server>

</beans>
```

HelloWorldImpl.groovy

```
package at.pdts.cxf

import javax.jws.WebService

@WebService(endpointInterface = "at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    def halloService // inject HelloService. Initialize this bean via applicationContext.xml

    public String sayHi(String text) {
        return "hello " + halloService.scream(text)
    }
}
```

HelloService.groovy

```
class HalloService implements InitializingBean{

static transactional = false

String scream(String text) {
    text.toUpperCase()
}

// methods gets not called, so service bean is not initialized at the ws creation time
void afterPropertiesSet() {

   println "------> initializing bean HalloSerivce <--------
}
```

}

It seems that at the moment of the jaxwsService initialization the helloWorld service bean is not available.

Comment: Just so I understand, your Object `halloService` in `HelloWorldImpl` is an instance of a class called `HelloWorld`?

Comment: No, halloSerivce is a grails service artefact. i have added the service class code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed this the first time I read your question but you are defining your bean in `applicationContext.xml`. When I was making a test case for your question, I was putting my bean definition in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml`. Try creating that file and putting the following into it:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <!--create the bean for the service, link to groovy service bean -->
    <jaxws:server id="jaxwsService" serviceClass="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorld" address="/hello">
        <jaxws:serviceBean>
            <bean class="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorldImpl">
                <property name="halloService" ref="halloService" />
            </bean>
        </jaxws:serviceBean>
    </jaxws:server>
</beans>
```

As a side note, you can find more information about integrating Grails and CXF [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=85983334).

Comment: of cource, you're completely right! the property should refer the halloService bean. terrible typo. nevertheless i'm getting the same error. as you can see in my question the service class implements the InitializingBean to see when the service gets initialized by the framework. The method gets not called!

Comment: Since you fixed that typo and still have an issue, I think the problem is where you are defining your beans. I have updated my answer with new information.

Comment: defining the cxf serivce bean within the resources.xml file did the trick. it seems that at this time the halloService bean is already initialized and no extra bean definition is neccessary.

Answer (score 2):

This needs to point to something:

```
<ref bean="helloWorld">
```

Do you have something like this defined:

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="at.pdts.cxf.HalloServiceImpl" />
```

That error means that Spring could now find a spring bean with the alias "helloWorld."

Perhaps posting your entire spring.xml and the java code to HelloWorldImpl would help.

EDIT: Your config confirms my theory.

`<ref bean=` says "inject something else here". But you have not defined that bean, hence the exception No Such Bean Definition. Furthermore, I was able to make your code work by creating my own implementation of HalloService (HalloServiceImpl) with a custom scream method that returned a blank string. Then I added it to the spring configuration: `<bean id="helloWorld" class="at.pdts.cxf.HalloServiceImpl" />`

EDIT #2: Another way to make it work is by eliminating HalloService:

```
<jaxws:server id="jaxwsService" serviceClass="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorld" address="/hello">
    <jaxws:serviceBean>
        <bean class="at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorldImpl" />
    </jaxws:serviceBean>
  </jaxws:server>

</beans> 

HelloWorldImpl.groovy

package at.pdts.cxf

import javax.jws.WebService

@WebService(endpointInterface = "at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {


    public String sayHi(String text) {
        return "hello scream!" + text
    }
}
```

Basically your choices are: Provide Spring an implmentation of HalloService, or don't reference it in your Spring.xml.

EDIT #3: There is a misunderstanding around the purpose of InitializingBean:

From the javadoc:

> **InitializingBean** Interface to be implemented by beans that need to
>   react once all their properties have been set by a BeanFactory: for
>   example, to perform custom initialization, or merely to check that all
>   mandatory properties have been set.

Implementing InitializingBean just means that afterPropertiesSet() will be called. It does *not* mean the Spring will automatically add this bean to your Spring Config. You still must declare the bean in your spring configuration with this line:

```
<bean id="halloService" class="at.pdts.cxf.HalloService" />
```

Comment: thanks, but my problem is that at moments of the jaxws serivce init the service bean "helloWorld" is not availabe, because the init of serice artefacts happens at a later point in grails.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my response, and I'm not sure I understand you either. Can you try posting the items I suggested?

Comment: i have provided the requested items. if you like i can also provide a sample grails project.

Comment: Your configuration confirms my theory.

Comment: first of all thanks for your details answer. I have posted the service class code of HalloSerivce. My intention is to use a grails serivce in my web service implementation, because other modules would use this service either. You wrote that you use your own implementation of HalloService (HalloServiceImpl). Did you declare it as a grails service? Can you please share the source code of this class?

Comment: No, it was a a POJO, not a grails service. But your new edits have allowed me to figure out what you're trying to do: Replace this line: <ref bean="halloService"></ref> with this line: <bean class="at.pdts.cxf.HalloService" /> and you should be good to go. (Just make sure the package declaration 'at.pdts.cxf' is correct)

Comment: btw your assertion: "It seems that at the moment of the jaxwsService initialization the helloWorld service bean is not available." is because you aren't declaring the bean. Implementing InitializingBean does not mean spring automagically picks it up! If you just give my suggestion a try, you've got nothing to lose!

Comment: as i described before i needed to implement a grails service, because the logic is used in many other modules. so the second answer from seth.miller works for my purpose. thanks for your detailed answers and your effort!